# Google Play game services: socket-based messaging

Tags: android, multiplayer, google-play-games

I want to create *multiplayer 2D top-view race game* for 2-4 players. For multiplayer this game will use Google Play game services. Players will move their cars by roration device (accelerometer). This data I will send to all participant in room. Its realtime and this type of game needs, as exact as possible, positions and angle of cars for smooth animations, checking for objects collisions, display positions, etc …, so game must refresh fast enough to be smooth and work with given data.

Google Play game services multiplayer messaging has 2 concepts of exchanging game data between clients:

1. Sending real time message - *Reliable* (max 50 messages/sec) and *Unreliable*
2. Socket-based

Which concept I shoud use for exchanging players data?

Comment: We need a lot more information than this.

Comment: EDIT: I specified the type of game and available concepts of exchanging game data between clients

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something like this too and my plan is to build a prototype with Reliable Messaging first and see how that goes. If the latency turns out to be an issue, I'll then step down to Unreliable Messaging, and then if it's really not working out, Socket-based. As with any software project, having a good architecture will allow you to switch protocols relatively painlessly.

Also, there won't be any wasted work by implementing Reliable Messaging and then switching to Unreliable, since the programming required for Reliable Messaging is prerequisite for Unreliable Messaging.

It'll be nice too if someone with experience could answer this question right off the bat with what will and what won't work.

Comment: Hi, were you able to determine the latency in Reliable messaging, and whether it turned out to be an issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of developing an almost exactly identical game as you've described for my university project. We use AndEngine as the game engine.

We decided to go for Unreliable Messaging because we read that for quickly-updating games like shooters or racing games it's better to use a UDP-like protocol.

We've had 2 approaches:

- broadcasting my car's position to all other users - fairly straightforward and reliable, however with ~30 updates per second still not smooth enough,
- broadcasting my car's speed and direction whenever there's any change - very smooth results, however with Unreliable Messaging if any packet gets lost it turns out after some time that the position of the same car is different on different users' devices.

I would really like to upvote the issue and ask someone with experience in the matter to contribute :)